# App to print out fully expanded name of dates

Tags: грамматика, обучение

Is there any app where you would give in a date (for exmaple July 11th, 2015) and it would write out the correct way to say it in russain (i.e.  Одиннадцатого Июля две тысячи пятнадцатого года)? I want to practice this, but I am never sure I got it right - so such a tool would be cool to check for mistakes.

Comment: By default, it's Одиннадцатое, not Одиннадцатого. Strangely, "say" command in OS X does the same mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Склонение порядковых и количественных числительных по падежам
http://numeralonline.ru/

```
              11    апреля  1945   года 
              │              │
         ┌────┴───────┐  ┌───┴────────────────────────┐
          одиннадцатое   тысяча девятьсот сорок пятого  
         └─────┬──────┘  └─────────┬──────────┘└──┬───┘ 
             Имен.п.             Имен.п.         Род.п. 
             средн.р.
```

Answer (score 0):

Одиннадцатого Июля 2015 года я поехал в Москву.

Сегодня одиннадцатое июля 2015 года и я поехал в Москву.

Comment: Thank you for your post, but as it currently stands it is not an answer. Here some questions that may improve it: Are both lines "the right answer"? Which one is more preferrable? What is the difference in usage? Why is Июль is written in capitalized form?